# SyntaxError in Look#input in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu-11.04

I'm new in RoR and I test with "Débuter avec Ruby on Rails". It's in french of "Begining Ruby on Rails" by Steven Holzner. I have SyntaxError in `Look#input`:

```
Showing /home/rene/ruby_dev/ch05/txt2fields/app/views/look/input.html where line #9 raised:

/home/rene/ruby_dev/ch05/txt2fields/app/views/look/input.html:9: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...rt_form_tag ({:action => "at"}, {:method = > "post"} ));@out...
...                               ^

/home/rene/ruby_dev/ch05/txt2fields/app/views/look/input.html:9: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')'
... => "at"}, {:method = > "post"} ));@output_buffer.safe_conca...
...                               ^

/home/rene/ruby_dev/ch05/txt2fields/app/views/look/input.html:12: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...end= ( text_field_tag ("text2", "", ["size" => 30]) );@outpu...
...                               ^
```

Extracted source (around line #9):

```
6:     <h1>Les champs de saisie (champs de texte) version 2</h1>
7:     Cette application Ruby on Rails lit du texte saisi.
8:     <br>
9:     <%= start_form_tag ({:action => "at"}, {:method = > "post"} )%>
10:       Veuillez saisir votre nom.
11:       <br>
12:       <%= text_field_tag ("text2", "", ["size" => 30]) %>
```

Trace of template inclusion:

```
app/views/look/input.html  <=
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
form_tag :action => 'at', :method => post
```

and for your text field

```
text_field_tag "text2", nil, :size => 30
```